# Where is the email address for maillog set?

Tags: linux, centos, postfix

I've got a CentOS 6.7 system that currently emails a certain address to send system messages (for example, it emailed with the body "Terminated" to indicate a process spawned by cron that was killed when I restarted the server). However, I honestly have no idea where the email address it sends to was configured at.

If I look at `/var/log/mailog` I can see where it tries/does send the mails to that email address. But it doesn't seem to give me any good clues as to where it's configured to send to that specific address. Does anyone know where I might find that? I'd like to change it to a different address.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure 100% about what you are asking for, but if I understood, you want to send emails to `whatever@example.com` instead of `current@example.com`.

As they are system messages, you'd only need to edit `/etc/aliases`. There will probably be a line there saying:

`root:    current@example.com`

So, you would only need to change the email adress to your preference and then execute

`newaliases`

I think it's not needed to restart/reload postfix but I always like to do so for every service

`service postfix restart`

Documentation about `/etc/aliases` can be found [here](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html)